# How can I handle unwanted, non-erroneous situations better?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, sql-server-2016

When writing procedures, I occasionally encounter situations in which I want to abort the procedure, even if the situation didn't necessarily trigger an error.

Let's say, if I don't want John to be able to run this procedure, I'd do something like this:

```
IF @UserName = 'John'
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('John, get out', 16, 1);
    RETURN 1;
END
```

I don't really have a good reason for returning 1, it's mostly a remnant from shell scripting, and I'm open for better ways to do this.

Is there a better way of returning an error message and returning control to the caller for unwanted situations that aren't strictly speaking errors? I am not interested in reducing the amount of characters or lines of code. I just had a gut feeling saying "this is probably not the best way to solve this problem", and I was curious if there were smarter ways to do this.

One alternative could be by always using `TRY/CATCH`, since `RAISERROR` with a severity of 1-19 will hand control to the catch clause.

Example:

```
BEGIN TRY
    PRINT 'Before RAISERROR';
    RAISERROR('Time for errors', 16, 1);
    PRINT 'After RAISERROR'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(255) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    PRINT 'Inside CATCH'
    RAISERROR(@Msg, 16, 1)
END CATCH
```

Output:

```
Before RAISERROR
Inside CATCH
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Time for errors
```

Con: Requires the presence of `TRY/CATCH` blocks.

Comment: You should probably choose a better example... because the *correct* answer to this one would of course be "deny John permissions to execute the procedure".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a more terse way of returning an error message and returning
>   control to the caller for unwanted situations that aren't strictly
>   speaking errors?

You can use [`THROW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee677615.aspx)

> Raises an exception and transfers execution to a CATCH block of a
>   TRY…CATCH construct ... If a TRY…CATCH construct is not available, the
>   session is ended.

```
IF @UserName = 'John'
    THROW 50000, 'John, get out', 1;
```

The above is somewhat more terse as it is just a single statement and doesn't need the `RETURN` so you can also drop the `BEGIN` and `END`